# Procedure to create partition table on daily basis, truncate old partition & records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, partition

I have written 1 `Stored Procedure` where it should create new partition on daily basis, truncate partition & records older than 9 months. Below is the SP-

```
create or replace procedure sp_partn as 
 hm varchar2(255);
 mm varchar2(50);
 yr varchar2(50);
 dd varchar2(10);
 ym varchar2(50);
 dt varchar2(50);

 procedure tbl1_prtn as
 begin
  for i in (select partition_name, high_value from user_tab_partition where table_name='tbl1')
   loop
    hm := i.high_value;
    mm := substr(hm,6,7);
    yr := substr(hm,1,4);
    dd := substr(hm,9,10);
    ym := yr||mm||dd;
    dt := to_date(ym,'yyyymmdd');
    
   if sysdate >= add_months(dt, 9) then
      execute immediate 'alter table tbl1 drop partition' || i.partition_name;
   end if;

  end loop;
end tbl1_prtn;
begin
 tbl1_prtn;
end sp_partn;
/
```

When i execute above SP then neither partition create or neither drop partition of older than 9 months. (eg: tbl_20211116)

Comment: You may want to try *interval partitioning* (no need to create new partitions) and the [extended_partition_names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51143) to reference the partition to be dropped without using the *partition names*.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber So I need hash function to create new & delete old partition?

Comment: Nope, but you may use something like this for *drop partition* for a specific month (date stored in `my_month`) `execute immediate q'[alter table TAB drop partition for (DATE']'||to_char(my_month,'YYYY-MM-DD')||q'[')]';`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Not specific months but older than 9 months then will delete and also everyday today's date of partition will be create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
SELECT HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
```

because for a date partition, the HIGH_VALUE is normally something like "TO_DATE(' 2016-01-04 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'"  so I'm not sure your substr commands will work. A better option might be:

```
hm := i.high_value;
execute immediate 'select '||hm||' from dual' into dt;
```

which will be immune to string position etc.

Comment: Thanks Connor but I want older than 9 months then will delete and also everyday today's date of partition will be create. So i don't think it will delete partition & record older than 9 months and it create everyday today's date of partition.

Comment: My suggestion has nothing to do with *which* partitions you want to delete. This is just a more robust way of getting the date for a given partition.  You can then do whatever you want with that date (subtract 9 months etc etc)

Comment: When i execute SP then in table description not able to see partition name & index for the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you store dates as dates instead of strings it will make your life much easier and you can use INTERVAL PARTITIONs and this will solve your problem.

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR cc IN (SELECT partition_name, high_value --
  3                  FROM user_tab_partitions
  4                 WHERE table_name = 'TEST_TABLE') LOOP
  5        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  6           'BEGIN
  7               IF sysdate >= ADD_MONTHS(' || cc.high_value || ', 2) THEN
  8                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  9                     ''ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE DROP PARTITION '
 10                     || cc.partition_name || '
 11                     '';
 12               END IF;
 13            END;';
 14     END LOOP;
 15  END;
 16  /
```